# How to fix a data frame in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot 13 of 15 variables from my database with the ggplot2 package through a function. However, when I call the function I get an error related to the data.

The code is this:

```
dfplot.2 <- function(col)
{
  df <- my.data[,2:14]
  ln <- length(df)
  for(i in 1:ln){
    if(is.factor(df[,i])){
      ggplot(data=df[,i],aes(names(df)[i])) + geom_bar(width =0.5,fill="blue", colour="black")
     + ggtitle(paste("Distribucion de",names(df)[i]))}
    else{ggplot(data=df[,i], aes(names(df)[i])) + geom_histogram(fill="red", colour="black")
      + ggtitle(paste("Distribucion de",names(df)[i]))}
  }
}
dfplot.2(my.data)
```

The result for this is:

> Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector.

However my database was previously transformed to data frame with the function `as.data.frame(my.data)`.

Comment: what is the `my.data` dataframe?

Comment: @mischva11 thanks for your comments. my.data is a data frame with 15 variables and 70 observations

Comment: Hi, could you try replacing `aes(names(df)[i]))` with `aes(as.symbol(names(df)[i]))`? Without having a representative look of the structure of the data, it is hard to judge.

Comment: Pardon for the double comment, but I took a closer look. It looks like you are trying to pass only one column as the `data` argument, which will simplify to a vector. You could try `ggplot(data = data.frame(x = df[,i]), aes(x))`.

Comment: @teunbrand Sorry for answering late, but you were actually right about your suspicion, since he was passing a column as the data in the argument. Now I do not have the initial problem but the function throws me a NULL as an answer, but that is something I can solve in another way. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@Boris. We might be able to figure it out if you include the code that creates my.data.

There appear to be a couple of things going on here. The function refers to a data structure in its parent scope. It doesn't accept the data frame as a parameter. The error suggests you might not have my.data in your global environment anymore.

Meanwhile, I suggest you check out the data type of your variable and see what ggplot2 believes it to be. The following functions are useful to inspect that. Put these print statements inside your function right before the call to ggplot. The head() command will output the first few rows of whatever is in variable df.

```
print(class(df))
print(str(df))
print(head(df))
```

You can find out more about these functions on the installed help pages.

```
?class
?str
?head
```

Your function has a parameter, col, that is never used. Perhaps you intended to pass your data frame into the function in an argument?

The programming technique of outputting debug statements revealing the contents of your variables is called a trace. If you find you need to do a lot of that, then it starts to be worth it to come up with some sort of scaffolding for turning those print() statements on and off.

A few short traces like the ones I suggested are pretty easy to delete once you get the answer to your debugging question. This research is very useful and the technique can help you find many answers of your own. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Now I was running only the ggplot function testing with different my.data variables (outside the dfplot.2 function) and it generates the graphics perfectly. I really do not know what the problem with the function is